# How can i show uploaded files on the page using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have tried a code to upload a file on web server using Asp.Net C#. Code has no compilation errors, still in runtime it neither saves the file nor displays it in the grid-view. Where I am wrong? My current code is following:

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/resumes") + FileUpload1.FileName);
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
    foreach (string strFile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/resumes"))) {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strFile);
        dt.Rows.Add(fi.Name, fi.Extension);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Verified the path it takes? Made sure your method is even hit? Why are you passing a DataTable to the GridView? Why not bind it to some strongly typed class that will be easier to work with?

Comment: 1) You say it's not saving: Is `FileUpload1.HasFile` true? Is it executing the SaveAs method? Do you get any exceptions? Have you checked the folder manually to see if the file is there?

Comment: 2) Viewing: See the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx You can't add a row to the DataTable the way you're doing. The docs say "To create a new DataRow, you must use the NewRow method to return a new object. Such an object is automatically configured according to the schema defined for the DataTable through its collection of DataColumn objects. After creating a new row and setting the values for each column in the row, add the row to the DataRowCollection using the Add method."

Comment: i checked manually.. the files are saved over there.. that means query is working. but gridview is not showing it.. how can i solve that? and yes there is no error in the code neither any exceptions..

Comment: You didn't answer my question. *Why* are you using a DataTable`? Why not bind a `List<FileInfo>` object?

Comment: @mason can u please let me know how to do that?

Comment: "gridview is not showing it.. how can i solve that" I already told you how to solve in my second comment...you obviously didn't read it properly. But also the other comments are valid, there's no need to create a DataTable manually for this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding rows to your DataTable wrong. But more importantly, why use a DataTable? Do not use DataTable. There's no need for it. It's a pointless abstraction. You can bind an `IEnumerable` of objects directly to a GridView.  This allows you to take advantage of [strongly typed](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-strongly-typed-data-controls) objects.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/resumes") + FileUpload1.FileName);
    }

    LoadResumes();
}


protected void LoadResumes()
{
    var resumeFiles = new List<FileInfo>();

    foreach (string strFile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/resumes")))
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(strFile);
        resumeFiles.Add(fi);
    }

    ResumesGridView.DataSource = resumeFiles;
    ResumesGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Your GridView will need to be adjusted.

```
    <asp:GridView id="ResumesGridView" runat="server" ItemType="System.IO.FileInfo" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Extension" HeaderText="File Extension" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Extension Stongly Typed">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%#: Item.Extension %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note I'm showing the extension twice. The first way is less verbose, but not strongly typed. If you misspelled "Extension" for example, you would get an error at runtime, not compile time. The second way, it knows that `Item` is of the type specified by `ItemType`, so it can fail at compile time if we misspell `Extension` and it can also give us Intellisense code completion. It's better to fail fast.